# ¿Cómo llamar o invocar cada elemento de un for? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, botón

¿Cómo podría programar para que cada botón que se crea con el primer `for`, quede con los datos agregado por el segundo?

ej: Creo 4 botones, agrego 4 elementos y el resultado sea 4 botones con cada elemento que agregue en el segundo `for`:

```js
// cantidad de buttons
let ls = prompt('cuantos botones');

for (i = 0; i < ls; i++) {
    let $h1_1 = document.createElement('button');
    let = $h1_1Text = document.createTextNode('hola');
    $h1_1.append($h1_1Text);
    document.body.appendChild($h1_1);
    $h1_1.style.margin = '5vh';

    for (i = 1; i <= ls; i++) {
        var t = prompt('nombre' + " " + i);
        console.log(t);
        $h1_1.innerText = t;
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías redactar un poco mejor tu pregunta? o ¿Explicarla mejor?, para mí no queda claro lo que necesitas.

Comment: Tal como dice Daniel, mejora tu redacción por favor, sino va ser complicado entender que es lo que pides... Ve a [ask] para más información, y de paso puedes hacer el [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio...

Comment: ¿Como puedo hacer para que cada valor de la var t quede agregado en cada botón creado?

Comment: Ejemplo: creo 2 botones y al mismo tiempo en var t creo otros 2 elementos, y los elementos de var t queden guardados en los botones como texto

Answer (score 1):

Si no te he entendido mal lo que necesitas es que te pregunte cuantos botones quieres y a medida que los vaya creando vaya preguntando el texto con el que quieres que se muestren. Si es asi prueba con el siguiente codigo:

```js
// cantidad de buttons
let ls = prompt('cuantos botones');

for (i = 0; i < ls; i++) {
    let $h1_1 = document.createElement('button');
    $h1_1.style.margin = '5vh';
    let = $h1_1Text = document.createTextNode('hola');
    $h1_1.append($h1_1Text);

    var t = prompt('nombre' + " " + (i+1));
    console.log(t);
    $h1_1.innerText += ' ' + t;

    document.body.appendChild($h1_1);
}
```